# rails application undefined method for class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model, associations, has-many, belongs-to

I rewrote my create function in my scaffold Review after making it associated with my Concert model. When I try to submit a form to create a review though I get an error saying

> undefined method `reviews' for #Class:0xab9972c>

```
def create
    @review = Concert.reviews.create(review_params) 
end
```

My Concert model looks like this

```
class Concert < ActiveRecord::Base

validates_presence_of :artist
validates_presence_of :venue
validates_presence_of :date

has_many :reviews
end
```

and my Review model looks like this

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates_presence_of :artist
    validates_presence_of :venue
    validates_presence_of :date

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :concert
end
```

I also added the relations within my migration files but I still get the error. Can someone explain to me what is causing this and how I could go about creating a review that belongs to a concert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The association `has_many :reviews` is an instance method. I suspect that in your create method you want something like this:

```
def create
    @concert = Concert.new
    @concert.save
    @review = @concert.reviews.create(review_params) 
end
```

Comment: I tried that and now it says "You cannot call create unless the parent is saved"

so I'm guessing I need to do Concert.create instead of .new

Comment: Sorry. Yes, you need to do `@concert.save` first. And if you have any required fields or other validations, you have to fill in those fields before you save.